# awk freezing when I direct to a file

Tags: unix, awk, command-line-interface

So when I run this on a mac:

```
awk 'END { for (name in ENVIRON) {
  print "key: "name; }
}' >> app-deployment.yaml
```

awk just freezes. If I change it to just print to `/dev/null` like this

```
awk 'END { for (name in ENVIRON) {
  print "key: "name; }
}' < /dev/null
```

It works fine. Am I doing something wrong with my redirection? Is there something else I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: "reading from" (`<`) != "writing to" (`>>`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `END` to `BEGIN` to be able to work without any input:

```
awk 'BEGIN { for (name in ENVIRON) {
  print "key: "name; }
}' >> app-deployment.yaml
```

Answer (score 2):

> If an awk program consists of only actions with the pattern `BEGIN`, and the `BEGIN` action contains no `getline` function, awk shall exit without reading its input when the last statement in the last `BEGIN` action is executed. If an awk program consists of only actions with the pattern `END` or only actions with the patterns `BEGIN` and `END`, the input shall be read before the statements in the `END` actions are executed.
>
> **<sub>source: [POSIX awk Standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html)</sub>**

So in short:

- `awk 'BEGIN{ action-without-getline }'`: awk exits without processing any input files
- `awk 'BEGIN{ action-with-getline }'`: awk exits after processing the input files
- `awk 'END{ action }'`: awk exits after processing the input files
- `awk 'BEGIN{action}END{ action }'`: awk exits after processing the input files
- `awk 'BEGIN{action; exit}END{ action }'`: awk exits without processing any input files

But what if there are **no** input files specified:

> Execution of the awk program shall start by first executing the actions associated with all `BEGIN` patterns in the order they occur in the program. Then each file operand **(or standard input if no files were specified)** shall be processed in turn ...
>
> **<sub>source: [POSIX awk Standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html)</sub>**

So this just means that

```
$ awk 'END{action}'
```

will not hang, but awaits input from `/dev/stdin`

Answer (score 1):

***OP's Code1 analysis:***

```
awk 'END { for (name in ENVIRON) {
  print "key: "name; }
}' >> app-deployment.yaml
```

Doesn't have any Input_file passed to `awk` and `END` block in any `awk` code requires any Input_file to be passed,it hangs there since it is NOT able to find one.

---

---

***OP's Code2 analysis:***

```
awk 'END { for (name in ENVIRON) {
  print "key: "name; }
}' < /dev/null
```

Now you are passing `/dev/null` as an Input to `awk`(though it will NOT have any contents to be read by `awk` but still it has a Input passed to it), so as per rule once Input_file is done processing `END` block processes, in this case since NO contents are there so `END` section printing of statements should happen.

***To make `awk` code work without passing an `Input_file` way:*** In case anyone wants to `awk` to work without `Input_file` use only `BEGIN` section, which as per `man awk` page will be executed before `Input_file` gets processed so even you are NOT passing any Input_file it will NOT wait for its presence and once `BEGIN` section is executed it will come out of program.