# AWK adding digits in a number which represents result of a command

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I'm trying to learn bash shell scripting and awk, and I wrote some simple code that loops through the arguments given, and if params contain digits, I print the digits only.

Next, using AWK, I would to add them one by one and print the sum. And I'm stuck here. This is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

for user in "$@"
do
  echo "$user"
  if [[ $user =~ [0-9]+ ]]; then
    usersDigits=$(echo $user | tr -dc '0-9')
    echo "$usersDigits"
    echo "has digits"
    echo $(awk '{ sum+=$usersDigits } END { print sum }')
  else
    echo "doesn't have digits"
  fi
done
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you might want to assign bash variables with `-v` and then use it like here `echo $(awk -v awkVar= $usersDigits '{ sum+=$awkVar } END { print sum }') ` ..try this

Comment: andra - You're trying to install your car's steering wheel inside your television. Just like you can have a television in your car, you can have an awk script inside a shell script but that does not mean that awk is shell. They are 2 completely different tools with their own languages/scope/syntax/semantics. See http://cfajohnson.com/shell/cus-faq-2.html#Q24 for how to use the value of shell variables inside awk scripts. @JBone - no, there are multiple problems with that 1 line of code you suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Your code will be stuck since awk is expecting an input file or data from STDIN. You can add /dev/null if you don't want to process any files. You can read [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55617427/awk-freezing-when-i-direct-to-a-file) to understand more on that.

2) Even if you correct that, sum will not be calculated since the variable sum will be reset during every loop as awk considers it as a new variable.

Please note the difference in the output in the following 3 attempts:

```
for user in "$@"
do
  printf "\nUser: $user \n"
  if [[ $user =~ [0-9]+ ]]; then
    usersDigits=$(echo $user | tr -dc '0-9')
    echo "$usersDigits"
    echo "has digits"
    printf "First Try : " &&  awk 'END {print $usersDigits}' < /dev/null
    printf "Second Try : " &&  awk 'END {print "$usersDigits"}' < /dev/null
    printf "Third Try : " && awk -v dg="$usersDigits" 'BEGIN {printf "Digits= " dg; sum+=dg; print "  Sum= " sum}'
  else
    echo "doesn't have digits"
  fi
done
```

Output for "test.ksh acs acs005 acs007" is:

```
User: acs
doesn't have digits

User: acs005
005
has digits
First Try :
Second Try : $usersDigits
Third Try : Digits= 005  Sum= 5

User: acs007
007
has digits
First Try :
Second Try : $usersDigits
Third Try : Digits= 007  Sum= 7
```

In first two, usersDigits is undefined inside awk. I hope it helps.

Update:
Script with logic to calculate the sum of digits

```
for user in "$@"
do
 printf "\nUser: $user \n"
 if [[ $user =~ [0-9]+ ]]; then
  usersDigits=$(echo $user | tr -dc '0-9')
  echo "$usersDigits"
  echo "has digits"
printf "Sum of Digits:" && awk -v dg="$usersDigits" 'BEGIN {while( dg+0 > 0) {digit=dg%10; DigSum+=int(digit); dg=int(dg/10);}; print DigSum }' < /dev/null
```

else
    echo "doesn't have digits"
  fi
done

Sample Output:

```
./test.ksh acs acs005 acs007 acs123 345

User: acs
doesn't have digits

User: acs005
005
has digits
Sum of Digits:5

User: acs007
007
has digits
Sum of Digits:7

User: acs123
123
has digits
Sum of Digits:6

User: 345
345
has digits
Sum of Digits:12
```

Comment: thanks @acs005 but this still doesn't add the numbers. If I put 123 as an argument, it displays the same, instead of 6. have any idea why?

Comment: Becuase that logic to add the individual digits is not in the code. The code snippet you have shown just parses the input string and checks whether it has any numbers in it. It doesn't further split that number into individual digits and adds them to calculate the total sum.

Comment: I have added the modified script to calculate the sum of digits. If you find it useful then mark the answer accordingly.